# Can not process the data on file after storing array

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

I have file that contains 20x20 matrix with random numbers. I've read the numbers on the file and then to store in the array. It seems I had not actually assign the numbers to array, because when I had print one of the number it displayed something like "||" instead of number, see the line  `cout <<array[0][1]`. My complete code is below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
#define length 20

int main(){

    char array[length][length];

    char chs;


    ifstream  grid;
    grid.open("D:\\Example\\digit.txt", ios::in);
    while (!grid.eof()){
        for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++){
                    grid.get(chs);
                    if (!grid.eof()){
                        array[i][j] = chs;
                        cout << setw(1) << array[i][j];///It display the numbers on file, there is no problem here.*/
                    }
            }
        }
    }

cout <<array[0][2];//There is problem it can not display the number it display something different than numbers.
grid.close();
while (1);
}
```

Output of the consol, the numbers on the file exactly look like this. `cout <<array[0][3]` does not print

[image: Output of the consol, the numbers on the file exactly look like this]
I've changed the last part

```
cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++){

                cout << array[i][j];
            }
        }
    cout << endl;
    grid.close();
```

Output of the last part that is different than numbers on the file

[image]

Comment: You declare length variables for 20, and then don't use them and are using magic numbers of 19 for your read process.. it's not the issue but that is pretty bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner loop only runs for the current value of `i`, meaning that you read no values into the first row, 1 into the second row etc.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
//                      ^ wrong
```

If you want to read a 20x20 matrix, both your inner and outer loop should run for 20 iterations.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++){
//                      ^^
```

Note also that you probably need to add some code to handle any newlines in your input file. After each set of 20 digits, you'll have one (`\n)` or two (`\r\n`) characters indicating a newline.  These are a valid part of the text file but presumably aren't required to be stored in your array.

Comment: I've changed that, at this time cout << array[0][1] displays nothing

Comment: It works for me (ignoring the newline issue I've added to my answer). Can you add a sample input file to your question and update the code snippet to be a full program?  The problem now is in something you haven't shown us.

Comment: The last call to `cout <<array[0][1]` should print.  Try adding a newline - `cout <<array[0][1] << endl;`

Comment: Simonc, I have modified last part of the code to display as all contents of the array and I have added endl as you had mentioned. Yes, it displays something but not correct ordered and also display not all of them.

Comment: See my comment about you needing to handle the newlines in the file you're reading

Comment: Simonc I am so sorry you are right from starting, I found why for example arrays[0][0]=5 instead of 08, there is an issue in the if condition on the while statement, I have to replace it or consider when I will process the data anyway.